# Cannot create IBOUTLET from Storyboard to UITableViewController.swift (settings page)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have added a tableviewcontroller object for my settings page. On this settings page I have a slider and a UILabel. The UILabel is a number (1-10) which is changed via the slider.

To implement this, I need to create an IBOutlet to the UIlabel, however IB doesn't seem to let me create this. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to create it inside custom class of type `UITableViewCell` 
which should be assigned to that TableViewCell That contain your label.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it's `UITableViewCell` because it's a `UITableViewController`